# APP:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug

Tags: android

I have been looking for a long time, but the way on the Internet does not apply to me .

`Error`:

> Execution failed for task ':XLegendLoginSDKSample:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK values-th/values-th.xml
>       File1: D:\sysapi\Android\XLegendLoginSDKAS\facebooksdk4140\build\intermediates\bundles\default\classes.jar
>       File2: D:\sysapi\Android\XLegendLoginSDKAS\twittersdk231\build\intermediates\bundles\default\classes.jar

Comment: could you show us how and why the other ways dont apply to you?

Comment: For example, the following method is not applicable to me at all

Answer (score 1):

Insert  below lines in your app level gradle file

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: the way does not apply to me

Answer (score 0):

Hope to Useful

```
 defaultConfig
 {
  multiDexEnabled true
 }
```

Comment: the way does not apply to me